# Automatic formatting in C/C++/etc while typing in Neovim

Tags: neovim

I am new to Neovim, having moved from Emacs. One of the features I really liked and got used to in Emacs was automatic indentation and formatting while in different modes such as C++. I knew how to do this in Emacs and it was through the following added to my `.emacs`:

```
defun linux-c-mode ()
  "C mode with adjusted defaults for use with the Linux kernel."
  (interactive)
  (c-mode)
  (c-set-style "K&R")
  (setq tab-width 8)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq c-basic-offset 8))
```

It worked beautifully when I was editing any file with a `.c` extension: with the code text moving according to the C syntax. Similarly, for other kinds of files.

As an illustration, here is an animated gif of what I am looking for (in Emacs). Pardon my lack of typing skills that make it more painful to watch, but note that the indentation and formatting as happening automagically as I type in Emacs.

[image]

Is there similar code that I can put in my `.config/nvim/init.vim` or some other file like that?

So, if you see, what is happening in the animated gif is that as I am typing with Emacs, I write `for (`, the automatic indentation happens the moment I press the `(` and then when the brace opens next `{`, the indentation for the next line is automatic when I hit return key. Note that I am not actually having to press any key combination and formatting is happening according to the "Kernighan and Ritchie" style of C programming (as asked for in the style setting). This really helps in making fewer errors while writing code.

I looked into `formatter.nvim` at https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim but I am not sure it is possible to do what I am looking for automagically. Being new to `nvim`,  it is also quite confusing, and difficult to easily find suggestions because I am not sure what to search on.

For C bindings, I have found that adding the following to my `.config/nvim/init.vim' works fairly well:

```
autocmd BufEnter  *.c,*.h,*.C set cindent formatoptions=croq
autocmd BufLeave  *.c,*.h,*.C set nocindent formatoptions=tcq
```

However, I am still looking for better solutions.

Thanks for all the suggestions and the help, and my best wishes!

Comment: Try `:help :filetype` and follow the links to different things like per-filetype indent settings. This is also introduced at some point in the user guide.

Comment: Thanks @D. Ben Knoble, so automatic formatting of C/python etc files is possible in nvim, too?

Comment: Yes; I don’t have time to provide a full answer (or search for dupes) at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, @D.BenKnoble for your pointers and your help. I understand. Perhaps someone else can also help me out!

Comment: Regarding tabs, what's the expected behavior: should tabs turn into 8 spaces or should tabs remain `\t` characters that are 8 characters wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Auto-Indenting

Auto-indentation is a vast topic and I have no intention to cover it all but I can give some indication about the default automatic indentation for `cpp` `filetype`.

More information about C indentation with `:help C-indenting`.

By default for the `cpp` `filetype` the `cindent` option is on.

This ensure that automatic indentation is triggered by the key specified in the `cinkeys` option (more information with `:help 'cinkeys'`) following the `cinoptions` auto-indentation  style (more information with `:help 'cinoptions'`)

By default this means that auto-indentation will be triggered by:

- New line
- Closing bracket on empty lines
- <kbd>Ctrl-f</kbd>
- ...

## 2. Indentation Correction

The indentation of a line can be corrected in normal mode with `==`

The indentation of a range of line can be corrected using the `=` operator (e.g. `gg=G` for the entire program, `=` for the selected lines, `=a{` for the current scope, method or function, ...)

## 3. Formatting

For the formatting there are multiple solutions:

1. Based on external program and Vim filtering
2. Based on formatting plugins
3. Based on LSP engine

### 3.a External Program

A popular choice for formatting `cpp` program is [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

It reads from standard input and, based on the formatting option set in `~/.clang-format`, writes formatted output to the standard output.

You can format your `cpp` code using the following Vim/Neovim command:

```
:%!clang-format
```

The clang-format documentation as a [Vim Integration](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#vim-integration) section to provide partial formatting (when you want to format only a part of your code)

For Python a popular choice for formatting is [black](https://github.com/psf/black).

You can format your `python` code using the following Vim/Neovim commnand:

```
:%!black -q -
```

For partial Python formatting there is a [black-machiato](https://github.com/wbolster/black-macchiato) plugin that provides it (I wrote some [pull requests](https://github.com/vds2212/black-macchiato) to solve some small problems with black-macchiato).

#### 3.a.1. The gq Command

The formatting command of Vim is `gq`, among other things it allows you to associate a program to the command via the `formatprg` option (more information with `:help 'formatprg'`).

For cpp you could do:

```
set formatprg=clangformat
```

With that set:

- `gggqG` will format your entire `cpp` file,
- `gqa{` will format the current scope (function or method).
- ...

### 3.b Formatting Plugins

Under the hood they will use the same filtering technique but they will provide you with minimal configuration:

- A common command to format the code for several languages
- The possibility to automatically format on save

Some popular example of such plugins are:

- [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat) and the `:Autoformat` command
- [neoformat](https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat) and the `:Neoformat` command
- [vim-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier) and the `:Prettier` command

### 3.c LSP engine

Some of the LSP engine, that are known to provide source completion, also offers code formatting. If you install a plugin that bridge Vim/Neovim with a LSP engine they will come with formatting command.

The [coc-nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) comes with the `Format` option.

The [lsp-formatting](https://github.com/lukas-reineke/lsp-format.nvim) plugin offer formatting based on the builtin LSP bridge of Neovim

Comment: Thank you very much for this, @VivianDeSmedt! This is great and very helpful, but  I also wonder it it is possible to have the formatting happen automatically as I type specific keywords (in C in the above emacs example). All these formatting tools require some action (save file, for example) while pressing a key. I have been looking for something that does this automagically as some keyword is typed.

Comment: I don't know much the solution in Emacs and in the example you posted the formatting I see is more what we call auto indentation. Could you give us an example of what you expect (correction of indentation, correction of the white space, correction of the return value, addition/removal of brace `{`, ...)?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is autoindentation, but it is happening automatically as I type. I d not have to do any key combination, and is happening by typing and based on keyword. Thanks!

Comment: For auto indentation I'm aware of two kind of support in Vim. 1. The auto-indentation when you go to a new line or when you open a brace `{` or close a brace `}` 2. The auto-indentation operator `==` or `=` movement (e.g. `=G`). I'm not aware of something that automatically indent your code when you start a line from position 0. I would either start from the previous line and create a new line or start with the wrong indentation finish my line leave for normal mode and hit `==`.

Comment: THank you again, @VivianDeSmedt, your suggestions above have provided me with a wealth of references to check out. I will also look at auto-indentation, though I feel it should be possible to do what emacs is doing. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If you have the solution in one of the answer it would be good if you could accept one using the v button next to the arrow voting button. If you have not feel free to add your own solution that you'll be able to accept yourself after two days. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: I was wrong when saying you have to leave insert mode to auto-indent you can use the Ctrl-f key for that :-) I have updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @Vivian De Smedt, I am looking into it. I alos found a simple way to handle this in C files. But let me understand the rest. And yes, I will accept the best answer. Thanks again!

Comment: For now, I accept your answer: let us see if something better shows up too.

Comment: You might also mention formatprg to make gq run the program of your choice. I also like to include (for example) `=a{` to show more interesting uses of operators beyond `gg<op>G` and visual mode.

Answer (score 1):

If I read the emacs code correctly, what you want are the three options:

```
set cindent       " use indentation for C code
set shiftwidth=8  " indent is 8 spaces
set noexpandtab   " keep tabs as tabs, don't expand to spaces
```

See `:help cindent`, `:help shiftwidth` and `:help expandtab` respectively to see what these options do.

Vim's automatic filetype detection will enable `cindent` for C files (among other things). So you should switch it on (in NeoVim, it's on by default) and override the other two options e.g. by adding the following file or an autocommand that triggers when `filetype=c` is set.

In `after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
setlocal shiftwidth=8
setlocal noexpandtab
```

Alternatively, define an autocmd in `init.vim`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
augroup linux_kernel_indentation
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c setlocal shiftwidth=8 noexpandtab
augroup END
```

Again, refer to `:help :filetype` and help for the respective commands.

The lines above are for a classic `vimrc` so you need to translate them into Lua if you want them in an `init.lua`.

BTW, [Linux Kernel Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#indentation) mandates to use spaces instead of tabs, that would mean `set expandtab`. I may have simply misread the emacs code.

Comment: Adding the above to my `.config/nvim/init.vim` does not appear to do anything.

Comment: @user3236841 does it work if you set the options manually?

Comment: Yes, it does. Interesting!

Comment: Okay, so that's what Vim can do out of the box. I can do a little research on how to translate it to NeoVimese later this day and will update my answer.

Comment: Might as well use `after/indent/c.vim` if you’re turning on indent scripts; no need for the extra autocommand.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble should be `after/ftplugin/c.vim` as we're not setting `indentexpr`. That was actually my first thought. Frankly, I have no idea where NeoVim would look for these files so I went for the `autocmd` - and failed :-)

Comment: They should use the same rtp files for ftplugins and such.

Comment: I checked last night and indeed, it should work like this. I also updated with the (preferred, IMHO) solution of using a file in after. If it doesn't work, double-check if filetype was set with `:set ft?`.